# How to get final redirected url with angularjs's $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

Is there any way to access xhr.responseURL with angularjs's $http?

There is a article on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseURL) explains how to do with raw xhr. But i couldn't find any solution to access xhr object with angularjs.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532639/access-raw-xhr-object-using-http

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by modifying the $xhrFactory

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.factory('$xhrFactory', ['$rootScope', ($rootScope) => {
    return function createXhr(method, url) {

        // configure the xhr object that will be used for $http requests
        const xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest({ mozSystem: true });

        // attach an handler 
        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {

                /*
                you can restrict local xhr calls
                if (xhr.responseURL.startsWith('file://')) {
                    return;
                }
                */

                // broadcast xhr object to root scope
                $rootScope.$broadcast('xhrDone', xhr);
            }
        };
        return xhr;
    };
}])
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope',  ($scope) => {

    $scope.$on('xhrDone', (event, xhr) => {
        // here is the responseURL
        console.log(xhr.responseURL);
    });

}])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.get(...)
    .then(function(response){
        //check response.status/headers/config/statusText
    })
```

See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http